# How can I keep the size after switching to full screen mode in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I only have the following so far

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel  Background="Red">
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="357"/>
        <StackPanel  Background="Gray"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I want this layout to be retained when the program is enlarged;
[image]

and not like it is now when I make it big:
[image]

How can i make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that, what you have wanted? By default the `DockPanel.LastChildFill` property is set to `true`. So if you enlarge the window, `StackPanel` in your case was enlarged.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel  Background="Red">
        <StackPanel  Background="Gray" MinHeight="75" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at grids, you can specify the height of the first row to 357 if you wish but Auto will just adjust to the contents on that row for you. * means fill the remaining space of the grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```